# Foreach loop through $characters php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am currently making a hangman game with php and am trying to print out the blank lines using:

```
$hidden = $_SESSION['hidden'];
  foreach ($hidden as $character){
  echo $character."  ";
  }
```

However, I am getting an error - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I was wondering what I did wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Do you use `session_start()` and how do you set `$_SESSION['hidden']`?

Comment: What php version are you running?

Comment: You can't iterate with `foreach` over a string. Use `for`.

Comment: Easier `echo implode(' ', str_split($hidden));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an array to use `foreach()`, you could use `for()` (loop along length of string) or simply use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to convert the string to an array...

```
$hidden = $_SESSION['hidden'];
foreach (str_split($hidden) as $character){
    echo $character."  ";
}
```